# Attempting to parse a date with unicode in Tableau using DATEPARSE function

Tags: datetime, unicode, tableau-desktop

I am attempting to use Tableau's "DATEPARSE" function to get a standard date/time format... so far my attempts have failed.

The format of the raw unicode date is: **2022-08-01T08:00:00-04:00**

I was successfully able to do the first part, but does anyone have an idea on the whole thing?

The first part: DATEPARSE("yyyy-MM-dd",[Date])

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out:

```
DATEPARSE("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ",[Date])
```